# Deploying OSGi bundle on Oracle 12c throws NPE

Tags: osgi, weblogic12c, apache-felix

On Weblogic 12.2.1, I am trying to deploy a simple OSGi Bundle as a war file using Admin console but throws NPE with following logs.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:

        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.getMainAttributes(JarRevision.java:210)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.getManifestHeader(JarRevision.java:104)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.createRevision(BundleImpl.java:1235)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.<init>(BundleImpl.java:112)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2905)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
```

As a prerequisite I created OSGi Framework (Services->OSGi Frameworks) based on Apache Felix. My Bundle is an API project with few interfaces which I wrapped in a WAR file. structure of war file is as below:

```
myapi-project.war
   - META-INF
   - WEB-INF
          - classes
          - lib
          - osgi-lib
               - api-project.jar
          - weblogic.xml
```

Weblogic.xml contents are:

```
   <wls:osgi-framework-reference>
   <wls:name>CPS-OSGi</wls:name>
   <wls:application-bundle-version>1.0</wls:application-bundle-version>
   <wls:application-bundle-symbolic-name>cpsservices.approval</wls:application-    bundle-symbolic-name>
   <wls:bundles-directory>osgi-lib</wls:bundles-directory>
```

API project MENIFEST.MF contents:

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Implementation-Vendor: BAML
  Implementation-Title: CPS API 
  Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
  Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
  Bundle-SymbolicName: cpsservices.api
  Bundle-Name: cpsservices api bundle 
  Bundle-Vendor: BAML
  Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
  Export-Package: com.bofa.cp.core, com.bofa.cp.services
  Bundle-Activator: com.bofa.cp.core.Activator
```

I have tried adding additional MENIFEST attributes but that didn't resolve the issue. I am stuck on this point for last 2 days. any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Update: Here is a screenshot of JarRevision class in org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar v4.4 which comes with app server Oracle 12.2.1 -
[image]

possible reason for this Felix cant read the MENIFEST.MF file for some reason. To confirm this understanding, I changed the Bundle Symbolic name in the file, but that didn't change the exception.
guess I am close ...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. guess what - Typo in MANIFEST.MF file name(created file name as mEnifest.mf). I need a break :)